# Elatisearch match_phrase_prefix query, with exact prefix match

Tags: elasticsearch, special-characters, match-phrase

I have a match_phrase_prefix query, which works as expected. But when the users passes any special characters at the end of the keyword, ES ignores these characters, and still returns the result.
`query{ match_phrase_prefix:{ content: { query: searchTerm } } }`

I am using this query to search for prefix. If i pass a term like **overflow@#@#!!** ES is returning me all the results with the word **overflow** in it. But instead i want to make an exact prefix match, where the special characters are not ignored. The search term could be of multiple words as well **stack overflow search**.
How could i make ES search of prefix_match without ignoring the special_chars.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `keyword` analyzer when defining your query.

```json
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase_prefix": {
      "content": {
        "query": "overflow@#@#!!",
        "analyzer": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```